# Stripe Payment Integration Issue on PHP Script

Tags: stripe-payments

Stripe is integrated on my website and was working fine till date, but facing the following issue when user click on payment button, Is there anyone who can suggest me the solution;

exception 'Stripe\Error\ApiConnection' with message 'Could not connect to Stripe (https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers). Please check your internet connection and try again. If this problem persists, you should check Stripe's service status at https://twitter.com/stripestatus, or let us know at support@stripe.com. (Network error [errno 28]: SSL connection timeout)' in G:\PleskVhosts***LINKHIDE***\vendor_2018\stripe\stripe-php\lib\HttpClient\CurlClient.php:317 Stack trace: #0 G:\PleskVhosts***LINKHIDE***\vendor_2018\stripe\stripe-php\lib\HttpClient\CurlClient.php(274): Stripe\HttpClient\CurlClient->handleCurlError('https://api.str...', 28, 'SSL connection ...', 0) #1 G:\PleskVhosts***LINKHIDE***\vendor_2018\stripe\stripe-php\lib\HttpClient\CurlClient.php(234): Stripe\HttpClient\CurlClient->executeRequestWithRetries(Array, 'https://api.str...') #2 G:\PleskVhosts***LINKHIDE***\vendor_2018\stripe\stripe-php\lib\ApiRequestor.php(400): Stripe\HttpClient\CurlClient->request('post', 'https://api.str...', Array, Array, false) #3 G:\PleskVhosts***LINKHIDE***\vendor_2018\stripe\stripe-php\lib\ApiRequestor.php(125): Stripe\ApiRequestor->_requestRaw('post', '/v1/customers', Array, Array) #4 G:\PleskVhosts***LINKHIDE***\vendor_2018\stripe\stripe-php\lib\ApiOperations\Request.php(57): Stripe\ApiRequestor->request('post', '/v1/customers', Array, Array) #5 G:\PleskVhosts***LINKHIDE***\vendor_2018\stripe\stripe-php\lib\ApiOperations\Create.php(23): Stripe\ApiResource::_staticRequest('post', '/v1/customers', Array, NULL) #6 G:\PleskVhosts***LINKHIDE***\charge.php(48): Stripe\Customer::create(Array) #7 {main}

Comment: As the top line says, this is simply an issue with the internet connectivity on the device you were using.

Comment: Hey @RussJ , It's not the issue with the internet. Facing the same issue on all devices.

Comment: Also verify your own server settings to make sure there is nothing on your end blocking the connection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36824432/stripe-api-connection-error

Comment: If that doesn't work, I would contact Stripe support.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused bu an overaggresive firewall or some kind of IP blockage on your server.

If you are using some kind of whitelist for outbound connections or inbound connection whitelist the IPs and hostnames listed here: https://stripe.com/docs/ips

This will make it possible for stripes servers to communicate.